# marco running extremely slow and doesnt return result

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to make unique identifiers in two different worksheet and do a loopup see if any unmatch, if there is unmatch, will indicate "new this month" on sheet1, however, my code below is running very slow and I did not even get the result, please help

```
Sub Mycomp ()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow2 As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Dim sht4 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim a As Integer


Dim mycompariosn As Integer


'concatenate column 1and column 5 in sheet 1, and generate result in column 20

lastrow2 = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

For n = 1 To lastrow2

Worksheets(1).Cells(n, 20).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Value & Worksheets(1).Cells(n, 5).Value

Next n

'concatenate column 1and column 5 in sheet 1, and generate result in column 20

lastrow = Worksheets(4).UsedRange.Rows.Count


For a = 1 To lastrow

Worksheets(4).Cells(a, 20).Value = Worksheets(4).Cells(a, 1).Value & Worksheets(4).Cells(a, 5).Value

Next a

'compare the two column 20 in sheet 1 and sheet 4, find any new row in sheet1 with a return "New in This month" if it is new

For n = 1 To lastrow2
    For a = 1 To lastrow

    mycompariosn = StrComp(Worksheets(1).Cells(n, 20).Value, Worksheets(4).Cells(a, 20).Value, vbTextCompare)

    If mycompariosn = 1 Then Worksheets(1).Cells(n, 7).Value = "New in This month"

    Next a

Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: You already have 18 answers on all your previous 9 question and none of them is accepted. Doesn't suit? Consider about [accepting previous answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) before posting new questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions first

1. Do not use `Integer` as a variable type for rows in Excel. Use a `Long`. You may get `Overflow` errors in xl2007+
2. Please do not use `UsedRange.Rows.Count` to get the last row in a worksheet. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Now to address your question.

Instead of using a loop, use a formula to make your code faster. Also simply concatenating may not give you the correct result. For example, once you concatenate the below, it will be the same but are they actually the same?

```
Cell 1    Cell 2    Concatenate Cell

Sid       Rout      SidRout
Si        dRout     SidRout
```

To overcome this problem, use a delimiter which has not been used in a sheet. Perhaps something like "#YourName#"? So the above looks like

```
Cell 1    Cell 2    Concatenate Cell

Sid       Rout      Sid#user2864813#Rout
Si        dRout     Si#user2864813#dRout
```

Next thing is you can use `.Formula` instead of looping. That will make your code faster. See this example.

```
Const Delim As String = "#user2864813#"

Sub Mycomp()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)

    With sht1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        With .Range("T1:T" & lRow)
            .Formula = "=A1 & """ & Delim & """ & E1"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

    With sht2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        With .Range("T1:T" & lRow)
            .Formula = "=A1 & """ & Delim & """ & E1"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Now instead of looping to find matches, you can again use `.Formula` to find a match for whatever you are looking.

If you are doing a cell to cell match in a particular row then use this code to generate the result in col 21 or whatever empty column that you have.

```
sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Formula = "=T1='" & sht1.Name & "'!T1"
sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Value = sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Value
```

If there is a match then you will get a `TRUE` else you will get a `FALSE`

If you are not doing a cell to cell match in a particular row but checking for the existence of a word in a column then use `=Countif()`. Something like this

```
sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & sht1.Name & "'!T:T,T1)"
sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Value = sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Value
```

If you get a value greater than `0` then there is a match found :)

Hope this gets you started.

**Disclaimer**: The above code is `UNTESTED` so please let me know if you face any problems.

Comment: Glad to see you again here:) you have two little typos: 1) correct would be `.Range("T1:T" & lRow).Formula = "=A1 & """ & Delim & """ & E1"` and 2) I would also add `'` in lines `sht2.Range("U1:U" & lRow).Formula = "=T1='" & sht1.Name & "'!T1"` and `.Formula = "=COUNTIF('" & sht1.Name & "'!T:T,T1)"` for case when sheet name contains spaces:)

Comment: Thanks simoco :)  I am traveling at the moment so feel free to edit the answer.  Like I mentioned that the above code is not tested.